# Disabling UIBarButtonItem with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to disable a `UIBarButtonItem` in my iOS app when a condition has been met.

So in my `viewModel` I created this signal:

```
-(RACSignal *)thresholdLimitReachedSignal
{
    @weakify(self);
    return [RACObserve(self, thresholdLimitReached) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
            @strongify(self);
        return self.thresholdLimitReached;
    }];
}
```

Then in my `viewController` I have this:

```
self.requestNewPinButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc]initWithEnabled:self.viewModel.thresholdLimitReachedSignal
                                                                   signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {

           [self.viewModel.requestNewPinSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {

                   //do some stuff here
           }];
           return [RACSignal empty];
       }];
```

So the `UIBarButtonItem` is triggered and fires off a `requestNewPinSignal` which works just fine. Then I flag `thresholdLimitReached` which causes the thresholdLimitReachedSignal to fire - all good. However the button just does not get disabled and I am not sure why? No matter if I manually set the boolean to `true` or `false` inside the `thresholdLimitReachedSignal` method - button remains enabled!

If I manually subscribe to `thresholdLimitReachedSignal`
like so:

```
[self.viewModel.thresholdLimitReachedSignal subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    self.requestNewPinButton.enabled = NO;
}];
```

Then button gets disabled no problem. I'd like to have this signal combined with the requestSignal some how - I thought `initWithEnabled:signalBlock` did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[RACObserve(self, thresholdLimitReached) filter:^BOOL(id value) {
        @strongify(self);
    return self.thresholdLimitReached;
}];
```

You're filtering `thresholdLimitReachedSignal` so that it only ever returns `YES`, so your button is always going to be enabled. For starters, you could rewrite that like this and avoid the `@weakify`/`@strongify`:

```
[RACObserve(self, thresholdLimitReached) filter:^BOOL(NSNumber *thresholdLimitReached) {
    return thresholdLimitReached.boolValue;
}];
```

But don't do that: if you're using this as the enabled signal, it needs to be a signal of booleans that sends `YES` when it should be enabled and `NO` when it should be disabled.

Assuming that your want the button to be disabled when the threshold has been reached, you want something like this:

```
[[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[RACObserve(self.viewModel, thresholdLimitReached) not]
                        signalBlock:...];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That clears it up a little. I made the changes you suggested - however I am getting an a crash with the following:
" -not must only be used on a signal of NSNumbers."

Comment: @Tander what is the type of the `thresholdLimitReached` property? I assumed it was a `BOOL`.

Comment: Yes it is. I see the mistake - in your example above you have thresholdLimitReachedSignal in the RACCommand instead of thresholdLimitReached. Teaches me for just copy + pasting code without checking lol. This works perfectly - Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad; fixed.